# Swift 3 Generic parameters

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
    public func subscribe<T: PFObject>(subclassType: T.Type = T.self) -> Subscription<T> {
    return Client.shared.subscribe(self)
}
```

Error: Extension of a generic Objective C class cannot access the class's generic parameters at runtime.

Any suggestions please? It's an extension for PFQuery.

Comment: Here's a clue https://swift.org/migration-guide/ (look for that exact error message) but for that use case (I guess you're trying to migrate LiveQuery to Swift3?) it will probably involve changing other aspects of the code, and not just that in isolation.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to migrate LiveQuery to swift 3. I modified all other errors, i just have this one left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the same thing and got stuck at the same point for a while. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
    public func subscribe(_ subclassType: Any) -> Any {
       return Client.shared.subscribe(self as! PFQuery<PFObject>, handler: Subscription<PFObject>()) as Subscription
    }
```

By the way, I submitted an initial PR for the Swift 3 version of LiveQuery.. any help is very much appreciated! https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX/pull/68

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it now!